# How can I tell when an object reaches the end of the visible window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game. I have an arena of 15000x15000 pixels. Obviously, no existing screen has that many pixels, so I have the user scroll using arrow keys to change the window. I want to be able to detect when my object, this.localTank, reaches the edge of the viewable window so that I can then scroll the window as necessary. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you know the position and the dimensions of your tank and the screen:  `screen.newX = Math.max(Math.min(screen.x, tank.x), tank.x + tank.width - screen.width);` assuming that the registrations point of your tank and screen is left.

Comment: Please provide us some code you've already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` `.right` property, `window.innerWidth`

```css
body {
  width: 15000px;
}

#tank {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tank">tank</div>
  <script>
    var tank = document.getElementById("tank");

    function getTankPosition() {
      var left = window.getComputedStyle(tank).left;
      tank.style.left = parseInt(left) + 50 + "px";
      if (tank.getBoundingClientRect().right >= window.innerWidth) {
        // do stuff
        console.log(tank.getBoundingClientRect().right, window.innerWidth);
      }
    }
    
    tank.addEventListener("click", getTankPosition)
  </script>
</body>
```